# Paramiko SSH python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I´m trying the simplest way to make a SSH connection and execute a command with paramiko

```
import paramiko, base64
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('10.50.0.150', username='XXXXX', password='XXXXXX')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('show performance -type host-io')
for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
client.close()
```

------------ERROR-----------------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 5, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('show performance -type host-io')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.10.1-py2.6.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 374, in exec_command
    chan.exec_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.10.1-py2.6.egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 218, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko-1.10.1-py2.6.egg/paramiko/channel.py", line 1122, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
EOFError
```

If i execute this code changing the command it works and to another computer, this command works fine via SSH interative shell.

Any idea ?

Comment: Log in to the system (which raise the exception) and run the command. What do you get?

Comment: I get the expected results if I use linux ssh command.
The ssh server is Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version IPSSH-6.7.0

Answer (score 1):

After `client.connect(. . .)` you need to use this command

`session = client.get_transport().open_session()`

then use `session.exec_command(. . .)`.

Comment: I have a similar problem. The SSH command I am launching is long running (several minutes). What is the reason to create a session as you have shown?