# Is there any Robot keyword for starting a server(.sh) script and capture the response in a text file or a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, process, robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am having a ".sh" server script i want to run this file in my VM, after running i will send a curl request in my VM then this server will receive a response i want to capture the whole response in a file or variable. I have tried to run the server it was successful but i am stuck with how to capture the response also how to switch back to this server and capture the response after sending curl request.

```
CLI    COL_VM    cd server_path/                        prompt=$  timeout=30
${result}      CLI    COL_VM    ./server.sh             timeout_exception=0
```

where COL_VM is the device details which will help to login to that VM.

Comment: Have you tried- http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Open%20Connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to capture the response from server, i captured the curl request's response itself.

```
${curl}      CLI    COL_VM    curl -X GET \http://localhost:8083/Path \ -d 'curl_request_json_which_we_are_sending'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your VM has ssh enabled one of the options would be a custom library using Python's [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) interface. It is pretty simple to use. There were many questions about it here, e.g.

- [paramiko-ssh-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964414/paramiko-ssh-python)
- [python-paramiko-ssh-run-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30977849/python-paramiko-ssh-run-command)

I use it in Robot Framework to run commands and scripts on Linux servers and verify their output (both stdout and stderr).